# Select non-contiguous text / words anywhere

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, text, shortcut

How do I select text that is not together separately, for example:

`ThiS is SomE sampLe teXt`

or...

`THIS is SOME SAMPLE text`

(I want the characters in capitals to be selected).

I know I can use <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Select text</kbd> in Word and TextEdit, but I'm looking for a universal method to do this (not just in text editors - I want to do this in Safari, Chrome etc...)